# Geometry: coordinate graph question. Round each side length to the nearest tenth before adding.

Tags: geometry

The coordinates of the vertices of ΔMDT are M (4, −3),D (−6, −1), and T (7, −8). Identify the perimeter of ΔMDT. Round each side length to the nearest tenth before adding.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem will find the distance between each pair of points.

Comment: You have to find 3 distances: one from (4,-3) to (-6,-1)   , another from (-6,-1) to (7,-8)   , and the last from (7,-8) to (4,-3).  Then add the 3 lengths together.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula for distance between points:

$$d=\sqrt{(x_2−x_1)^2+(y_2−y_1)^2}$$

Can you continue?